# Python error when attempting to import module (ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package)

Tags: python

As you can see from the below, this is so simple that it pains me to ask the question here, but I've spent countless hours trying to resolve it w/o success.

parent.py

```
    favorite_number = 1

    def my_favorite_number():
        print favorite_number

    my_favorite_number()

    from .child import *

    my_favorite_number()
```

child.py

```
    favorite_number = 7
```

How do I import a child module from a parent module so that the the child module overrides a variable in the parent module?

Comment: please add a little more detail

Comment: You should use packages. Create a directory named `parent` and rename `parent.py` to `parent/__init__.py` and `child.py` to `parent/child.py`.

Comment: JGerulskis, I've updated the question (was doing so when you wrote your comment).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: You should make that comment into a proper answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring: let's see if someone else wants to write a more detailed answer that explains what a Python package is.

Answer (score 0):

lets say i have a file `child.py` in the same dir of my `main.py` code

`child.py` contain only 1 string

```
favorite_number = 99
```

Now if i run my `main.py` i will get the following output

```
1
99
```

which mean that `favorite_number` variable have been changed to value which is defined in `child.py`

Note: This will not work if your `child` file has`.` prefix, rename it from `.child.py` to `child.py` and also edit the line in `main.py` where you're calling that child

```
from child import *
```

Comment: Could you explain a little further; are you importing child.py from main.py? I'm getting an error when I do this. Of course, I followed the advice from Andrea above (thank you Andrea) and it works fine.

Comment: follow the `Note` I wrote maybe it will fix your issue

Comment: The issue I'm having is how to override a variable from a child import; if I use a string, it's no problem and Andrea's answer works, but if it's a list in the parent (the __init__.py file) and I try to expand the list from the child.py module, I get an error that states the list variable can't be found. I suspect this is because child.py is trying to identify the original list object which it can't locate. How do I reference the original list object?

Comment: I cant get what you're doing in there, no matter if its string or list in child.py it works for both, can you post your changes so I can take a look whats going on

Comment: If you override the list object it would work, but try to do a list.append(value) and you'll get a variable not found error.

Comment: still working: http://freetexthost.com/ys0wisbvk6
`testLst` and `favorite_number` are defined as `List` object in `child.py`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77441/discussion-between-pypl-and-charles-sounder).